# RotateX in Raphael.js

Tags: javascript, raphael

I have drawn some elements on a Raphael paper and I need to rotate them so that it looks like a rotation about X axis. I know that Raphael is a 2D API and doesn't have something like this implemented, but I think I can somehow change the shapes so that it gives the impression of rotation in 3D.
So the question is : How should I implement a rotateX in Raphael.js or is there another API I can use for this purpose?

Comment: Depends what kind of effect you are after...is this of any use http://jsfiddle.net/vQRv5/ ?

Comment: Thank you. I implemented orthogonal and perspective projection functions so that my 2D objects looked 3D